# Clarification of working of strcpy() when char array has been initialized like this *Arr

Tags: c++, c-strings, strcpy

I was trying `strcpy` like this:

```
  int main()
  {
    char *c="hello";
    const char *d="mello";
    strcpy(c,d);
    cout<<c<<endl;
    return 0;
  }
```

Compiling this gives a warning and running the code produces a Segmentation fault.

The warning is:

> warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
>     char *c="hello";

The declaration of `strcpy` is: `char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );`

1. So where am I wrong (regarding the warning)? IMO I have used a `const char` and a `char`, same as the function's declaration.
2. Does `c*` or `d*` not allocate memory to hold `"hello"` and `"mello"`, due to 
   which it is throwing segmentation fault? How does the 
   initialization/definition of a variable like `c*` work?

Comment: `char *c="hello";` is no longer legal in c++.

Comment: I don't understand your problem solving. The warning points at `char *c = "hello";`, but you argue that you call `strcpy` correctly: The compiler doesn't even complain about that part.

Comment: ***How does the initialization/definition of a variable like c* work?*** Many compilers will put string literals in an unmodifyable area of memory (protected by the OS and / or hw).

Comment: Use std::string. Really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler warnings (and errors) always refer to a particular line of code (and a portion of that line as well). It's a good idea to pay close attention to where the problems are.

In your case, the warning is not about *calling `strcpy`*, but about *initialising `c`*. You're making a `char *`, a pointer to **modifiable** `char`, point to `"hello"`, a **read-only** string literal. That's what the compiler is warning you about.

This used to be possible in C++, but with the caveat that you must never actually modify the memory pointed to (since string literals are immutable). Since C++11, converting a string literal to a `char *` is expicitly forbidden and will generate an error instead of a warning.

The reason for the segfault should be clear now: you're trying to overwrite a piece of read-only memory with the `strcpy` call.

The correct solution is to use writable memory for storing the destination string. You could do it like this:

```
char c[] = "hello";
```

This creates a new `char` array, which is writable normally (just like any other local variable), and initialises the array with the contents of the string literal (effectively a copy thereof).

Of course, since this is C++, you should be using `std::string` to store strings and not bother with `char*`, `strcpy`, and other C-isms at all.

Answer (score 3):

Both variables are pointing to constant literal text.

Modifying constant literal text is undefined behavior.

Place the text into an array if you want to modify it:

```
char e[] = "fred";
e[0] = 'd';
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you are trying is for TurboC++ it seems. As drescherjm pointed out in the comments, the `char *c="hello";` is no longer legal in c++.

If you try out your code in Turbo C++, it'll work just as you expected, although this isn't the same case with the modern c++.

> So where am I wrong (regarding the warning)? IMO I have used a const char and a char, same as the function's declaration.

The warning is due to the reason mentioned above, plus the warning isn't on the use of strcpy, it's on the declaration.

> Does c* or d* not allocate memory to hold "hello" and "mello", due to which it is throwing segmentation fault? How does the initialization/definition of a variable like c* work?

Well, the compiler would just put the strings in to a random place in the memory and let the c/d pointer point to it. It's risky as you can lose the data if you make the pointer point to something else by accident.